# Toss a coin three times. Let X= #Heads - # Tails. Find the distribution function of X.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This is the way I think it should go: # of heads=$p$,  of tails= $1-p$ then

F(x)= \begin{cases}
  0, & \text{if } x < 0, \\
  \sqrt{x+1}, & \text{if }  0 \leq x < 1 \\
  1, & \text{if } x \geq 1
\end{cases}
$F_X(x)=P(X\leq x)=P(p-1+p \leq x)= P(p \leq \sqrt{x+1})= F_x(\sqrt{x+1})$

Comment: Not following.  There are only $8$ cases, just write them all out.

Comment: yeah i just realized it, I was just wondering about the distribution function of X part.

Comment: But I don't understand why you say, or appear to say, that $X$ can not be negative.  If I toss $TTT$ then $X=-3$, no?

Comment: I was trying to mold my "thinking of distribution function" into this question, but I just saw my mistake. Yes you are right $TTT= -3$, also $THT= -1$, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there are only $8$ possible outcomes, you can just write them out and compute the distribution of $X$ explicitly:

$$
\begin{array}{l|c} %l/c/r = left-align/centre/right-align | for a vertical bar
\mathrm{Outcome} & X = \mbox{#heads} - \mbox{#tails}\\\hline
HHH     & 3  \\
HHT     & 1  \\
HTH     & 1  \\
HTT     & -1  \\
TTT     & -3  \\
TTH     & -1  \\
THT     & -1  \\
THH     & 1
\end{array}
$$

Since each outcome is equally likely*, we have $P(X=-3) = P(X=3) = \frac{1}{8}$ and $P(X=1) = P(X=-1) = \frac{3}{8}$. Therefore

$$
F(x)= P(X\leq x) = \begin{cases}
  0, & \text{if } x < -3, \\
  \frac{1}{8}, & \text{if }  -3 \leq x < -1 \\
  \frac{1}{2}, & \text{if }  -1 \leq x < 1 \\
  \frac{7}{8}, & \text{if }  1 \leq x < 3 \\
  1, & \text{if } x \geq 3
\end{cases}
$$

*I just reread your question and it turns out your probability of heads is $p$ which is not necessarily $\frac{1}{2}$. However you can use the above logic to generalize to any $p$.

Comment: Okay I see how you did this problem then, so now I just have to generalize it to any p, but thanks I understand now!

Comment: @pwerth: you can use \begin{array} for tables. I've just edited your answer to do that and prettified the equation for $F(x)$. Feel free to undo if you don't like what I did.

Comment: @RobArthan thanks for the edit! I came across this thread http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables which seems to imply there is no good way to do tables, hence my initial attempt.

Comment: I just have one question, how did you get $\frac{1}{2}, if -1 \leq x < 1?$

Comment: There are 4 outcomes corresponding to the event where $-1\leq x < 1$: HTT, TTT, TTH, THT. So the probability of that occurring is $\frac{4}{8}$ or $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Wouldn't TTT= -3, and not $x \geq -1$?

Comment: Yes, TTT would give you $-3$. The point is that $F(x)$ is the probability that $X$ is less than or equal to $x$, not just equal. And $-3$ is less than 1.

Comment: Oh I understand now, I was getting confused because I wasn't focusing on $F(x)  = P(X \leq x)$ Thanks!